# How can an app automatically switch the wallet to the needed network?

Tags: solana-wallet-adapter

When using solana-wallet-adapter, transactions fail if I don't manually switch the wallet currenlty being used to the network selected in the wallet adapter. Is there a way to automatically switch the wallet to the needed network when user selects it?

Comment: Solana wallets don't have a switch network function similar to how EVM wallets usually do. You will need to manually switch networks in your wallet. Though, Glow Wallet does have a switch network option when connecting if it detects you're on the wrong network.